# Backbone JS 404 on htaccess ModRewrite

Tags: .htaccess, backbone.js

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^api api.php [QSA,L]
```

Which I can browse to just fine - both `/api` and something like `/api/5`

However, when I try to access the url via backbone I get a 404 error. Not really sure where to go on this one...

Comment: That's not much for us to go on, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. When you say "I try to access the url via backbone", are you sure the right url is being requested?  I could assume that you know what you are doing and did check to see that the requests are what you say you are via Firebug, Chrome Inspector, but the fact that you're clueless about why this is happening makes me want to make clear baseline facts.
2. Is there any `RewriteCond` previous to your rewrite rule that may make the url rewrite for only certain requests?   Maybe there's some condition you've accidentally included which means ajax requests would not be rewritten (ajax requests generally can be recognized through a few request headers).
3. Backbone.js does use the `PUT`/`DELETE` http verbs, which might be problematic on some http servers without additional configuration for your website.  I'm going to assume you're using Apache since you mentioned .htaccess --there is a tool that can use .htaccess with IIS but you didn't mention it.  But you seem to not even have any success `GET`ing any data.

Comment: 1. Ive used the inspector and everything's fine, I can copy the URL and paste it into the browser and it works fine. 2. I updated with my full htaccess file for reference. 3. I'm currently just pulling the collection from a json file using GET which works fine (I'm echo'ing it and can see the data through the browser).